# How to idiomatically define assignment operator for immutable classes?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

In C++ what is the idiomatic way to define `operator=` on a class that should be immutable. For example all its member variables are `const`.

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

class Binary
{
protected:
    const unsigned long size;
    const byte* bytes;

public:
    Binary(const unsigned long size);
    Binary(const Binary &b);
    ~Binary(void);

    Binary& operator=(const Binary &b);
};
```

where `bytes` is a pointer to a block of memory `malloc`ed at run time.

Do I define an empty assignment operator or let it use the automatically generated on which will obviously fail?

I am trying to implement and enforce **single assignment semantics** on a few select classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you are not going to reassign your members (using `const_cast` etc.), I would suggest to explicitly mention in your code that you are not using `operator =`.

In Current C++ standard, make it `private` and unimplemented:

```
class Binary
{
  //...
private:
  Binary& operator = (const Binary&);
};
```

In upcoming C++0x standard, `delete` it:

```
class Binary
{
  //...
  Binary& operator = (const Binary&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: You could also use boost's approach, and derive from [a class called `noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable), that does the dirty-work for you.  Here's some source code: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/noncopyable.hpp

Comment: would this same technique be applied to the `copy constructor` as well?

Comment: @Jarrob, yes it can be applied to any member method inside the `class` (for both C++ standard)

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: an immutable class _can_ be copied.